# Tooltips doesn't work on d3js

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I have a problem... I am not able to include tooltips.. i've tried to do it with d3noobs tutorial and with much other.. But it doesn't work..

I hope anyone can help me or fullfill the code!

Thanks a lot!

```
<pre>

<!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                        <div class="panel-body" id="gr1">

                            <svg id="graph"   viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"  width="1500" height="600"  ></svg>

                            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


                <div id="tooltip" class="hidden" style="left: 429px, top: 489.6px">
            <p><strong><span id="city">Dar es Salaam</span></strong></p>
            <p id="population">Population: 4 million</p>
        </div>          
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#FF4000", "#D7DF01", "#DF013A", "#fbf10d"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("#graph")
    .append ("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function make_x_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5)
}

function make_y_axis() {        
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(20)
}   

    function mouseover(d) {

            d3.select(this).style("fill", "orange");

            var mousecoord = [0,0];
            mousecoord = d3.mouse(this);

            d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("left", mousecoord[0] + "px")
                .style("top", mousecoord[1]-75 + "px");

            d3.select("#city")
                .text(d.city);

            d3.select("#population")
                .text(function () { return year + " population: " + comma(d["y"+year]); });

            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
        };
d3.csv("groupeddatafordefaultdashboard.asp?3", function(error, data) {
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);





    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )



  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Anzahl");


      svg.selectAll("circle")
                       .data(data)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                           (blah blah)

                       .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                       .on("mouseout", mouseout);



  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });



  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });



  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(20," + i * 50 + ")"; });





  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });






});


</script>

</pre>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579)?

Comment: I don't see any tooltips being defined/called in the code you've posted, which would explain why they're, er, not showing up. Try working through [this chapter](http://books.google.co.tz/books?id=1HeLQ7ew7mcC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=scott+murray+div+tooltips+d3&source=bl&ots=C32gbxbK4Q&sig=myxuF0Th_ePBn5SCLNG8nKon_vE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R_QqVKq3N_SPsQSVhoIQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=scott%20murray%20div%20tooltips%20d3&f=false) in the Scott Murray book. Plus, a [walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955408/show-label-when-mouse-over-a-circle/25957385#25957385) I did.

Comment: Yes.. the first link i've seen but it doesn't worked...


still not yet with your tutorial.... now the chart isn't working anymore.. White page!   code edited!